# Кавычки в иноязычном цитировании

Tags: пунктуация

Долго объяснять, откуда и как до жизни такой дошел, сразу пример даю, упрощенный немного.

*Это произошло в ‘Sid Meier’s Pirates!’ (1987) - первой, судя по всему, игре, где имя разработчика включено в официальное название.*

Опустить кавычки совсем тут нельзя, непонятны границы собственно названия. А тут еще сходный по графике апостроф путается внутри самого закавычиваемого названия.  Но в английском тексте в подобных случаях не должно бы быть русских елочек-лапочек, они там немного другой смысл имеют. Как быть? Оставить английскую одиночную кавычку?

Фразу нетрудно, конечно, перестроить, но это, как раньше говорили,  "неспортивно", нужно бы решение именно для этого случая - академического интереса ради.

UPD
Я уточню. Вопрос возник именно потому, что в названиях, написанных латиницей, "русские" кавычки обычно опускают. Это согласуется еще и с тем, что в английском двойные кавычки обычно используются только для цитат, всякие названия чаще обходятся без них, а при необходимости используются одинарные (внутри двойных, например). Но проблема в том, что у данном отрывке после названия идет еще и год в скобках. Без соответствующего оформления это вполне воспринимается как часть названия. Жирный текст и курсив не подходит, поскольку в предыдущем тексте подобного выделения не используют.

Comment: Что мешает использовать обычные двойные кавычки?

Comment: *Это согласуется еще и с тем, что в английском двойные кавычки обычно используются только для цитат, всякие названия чаще обходятся без них, а при необходимости используются одинарные (внутри двойных, например).* В британском английском не совсем так. Одинарные кавычки предпочтительны, в том числе и для цитат: https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-quotation-marks.html. А для цитат внутри цитат могут быть и двойные внутри одинарных (в примере как раз этот случай): *For quotations within quotations, double marks are used if the outer ones are single, and single marks if the outer ones are double.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Возможно, что я не совсем удачно выразился. Безусловно, одиночные кавычки предпочтительны. Двойные используют только от безвыходности - и **только** в цитатах. Вот что я хотел сказать. Использовать двойные для названия (даже если в нем есть одиночный апостроф) - не комильфо. Отсюда и вопрос. Впрочем, все это уже дела давно минувших дней. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужны там кавычки, они только затрудняют чтение. Используйте жирный или курсив. Английский сам по себе отлично выделяется на фоне русских букв, дополнительно очерчивать его не нужно.

Это произошло в Sid Meier’s Pirates! (1987) - первой, судя по всему, игре, где имя разработчика включено в официальное название.

Это произошло в **Sid Meier’s Pirates!** (1987) - первой, судя по всему, игре, где имя разработчика включено в официальное название.

Это произошло в *Sid Meier’s Pirates!* (1987) - первой, судя по всему, игре, где имя разработчика включено в официальное название.

Comment: Читайте вопрос внимательно. Не устраивает меня жирный, не курсив, Это к русскому языку не имеет отношения, нужно именно орфографическое (пунктуацианное) оформление.  А вот без кавычек не ясно, где именно кончается название.  К тому же не решается вопрос с восклицательным знаком, который оказывается в середине предложения.

Comment: @Мимоходов Куда-то вы далеко убежали, а как же прописная буква?! По правила вам нужно писать Sid meier's pirates! или Sid Meier's pirates! Давайте сначала решим этот вопрос. Будете соблюдать это правило?

Comment: @СергейИваненко По правилам языка оригинала _все три слова_ пишутся с заглавной буквы (как у вас в ответе). Там это, действительно, указывает на принадлежность к наименованию, а кавычки такого вида более характерны для цитат.

Comment: Названия, написанные латиницей, в кавычки не заключаются. [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)

Comment: Это верно - для фирм, компаний, банков и т. п. Лишь игра была "подобна" фирме или банку :) В данном случае она "подобна" книге, а названия книг в латинице - из области сносок или списков литературы. Но какие-либо кавычки и я бы здесь не ставил.

Comment: @СергейИваненко Давайте не будем решать надуманных вопросов. Название 'Sid Meier’s Pirates!' Три заглавных. Точка.  Ну и "Грамота" может писать все, что ей заблагорассудится. В её ответе есть рациональное зерно, но не надо обобщать.

Comment: @Alex_ander здесь без кавічек нельзя. Писал же в вопросе, граница не  видна. Без этой ситуации и вопроса бы не было. Вы же обходите этот момент, а без него ответ не в "тему".

Comment: @Мимоходов Я вас понял. Действительно, давайте не будем решать надуманных вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, опустить кавычки можно. Вспомнилась компания Yahoo! Все пишут ее название без кавычек — и ничего. У Вас восклицательный знак не мешает пониманию текста, то есть можно понять, что он относится к названию, других вариантов прочтения нет.

Дополнение.

Впрочем, если хотите поставить кавычки, то Грамота говорит, что это не ошибка. И рисунок кавычек в этом примере есть. Я не пойму, почему Вы ориентируетесь на английский текст при постановке кавычек в русском тексте.

> Вопрос № 239331
>   Нужно ли брать в кавычки названия произведений на иностранных языках?
>   Например: 
>    ...собравшиеся исполнили песню "Stranger in the night"
>   Является ли ошибкой употребление кавычек?
>   Спасибо
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Прежде всего отметим, что в справочниках по правописанию нет рекомендаций по орфографическому оформлению названий, написанных латиницей.
>   По мнению председателя Орфографической комиссии РАН д. ф. н., проф. В. В. Лопатина, названия литературных и научных произведений, произведений искусства, даже написанные латиницей, целесообразно заключать в кавычки (здесь на употребление данного выделительного знака влияет семантика наименования: в большинстве случаев написанные латиницей названия в кавычки не заключаются). Корректно: собравшиеся исполнили песню «Strangers in the night». В любом случае употребление кавычек здесь ошибкой быть не может.

Comment: *У Вас восклицательный знак не мешает пониманию текста, то есть можно понять, что он относится к названию, других вариантов прочтения нет*. Кабы так, вопроса бы не было. У меня после названия идут скобки, которые без кавычек смотрятся как часть названия. А вообще вопрос даже не в этом. Мне не нравятся ***русские*** кавычки, имеенно потому, что их=то обычно опускают - не смотрятся они при английском тексте.